# export module return object with added method

Tags: node.js

I have the following codes :

```
app.post("/login/auth", (req, res) => {
    (async function() {
        let NikitaBellucci = (await auth.login(req, db, crypto))[0];
        res.send(NikitaBellucci);
    })();
});
```

and

```
exports.login = (req, db, crypto) => {
    pro = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let pseudo = req.body.pseudo;
        let password = crypto.createHmac('sha256', req.body.password)
                       .update('jojofags suck')
                       .digest('hex');
        let query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.pseudo = ? AND users.password = ? LIMIT 1";
        db.query(query, [pseudo, password], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err; // GESTION D'ERREURS
            result.isAdministrator = function() {
                if(this.role <= 90) { return true; } else { return false; }
            }
            resolve(result);
        });
    })

    return pro.then((val) => {
        console.log(val);
        return val;
    })
}
```

On `console.log(val);`, I can see the previously added method to my object. But when returning it to my main file, method "disappear", how to avoid that?

thank you

Comment: what exactly is the point of attaching that function to a temporary `result` object? it doesn't ever seem to be called, instead you just send raw data with `res.send(NikitaBellucci)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is attached to the entire result object, but you get the `0` property of it in `(await auth.login(req, db, crypto))[0];` which won't have the function. Just remove the `[0]` and `NikitaBellucci.isAdministrator` will be the function in question.